# Google app script trigger not fire after created

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to overcome exceeed time when looping, so I'm using trigger but trigger has never been fired. It stopped right after trigger was created

```
function runMe() {
    var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var startRow = scriptProperties.getProperty('startRow');
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    var range = sheet.getRange(10, column + 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 9, sheet.getLastColumn() - column);
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    for (var j = startRow; j <= numRows; ++j) {
        console.log('SheetIndex:' + sheetIndex + ', sheetName:' + sheet.getName() + ', startRow: ' + startRow + ', j:' + j);
        var currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        if (currentTime - startTime >= MAX_RUNNING_TIME) {
            scriptProperties.setProperty("startRow", j);
            ScriptApp.newTrigger('runMe')
                .timeBased()
                .after(REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT)
                .create();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the trigger was created but did not fire? What is the value of `REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT`?

Comment: @ziganotschka about 2 seconds (REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT = 2000)

Comment: And if you go on `Edit`->`Current Project triggers` - what can you see? Has the trigger been created? Is it disabled?